# Persistent Volume creation via kubectl stuck at Pending states

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create pv and pvc resources via `kuberctl create -f pv-definition.json` but k8s doesn't make any progress and it just kept reporting `Pending` states for them.

Looked at `kubectl get events` and logs from `api` and `controller`, but I don't see anything related to messages to pv or pvc creation. I have the disk created beforehand on gcloud and I have verified that the name and disk size matches.

The pv definition is very basic:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "PersistentVolume",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "test-0b-pv"
  },
  "spec": {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "capacity": {
      "storage": "50Gi"
    },
    "gcePersistentDisk": {
      "fsType": "ext4",
      "pdName": "test-0b"
    },
    "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Retain"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion for debugging? I have restarted k8s-master services to no avail.

Comment: What does your PVC definition look like?

Comment: @SaadAli

`{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "test-0b-pvc"
  },
  "spec": {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "resources": {
      "requests": {
        "storage": "50Gi"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Also tried modifying starting k8s-controller with `--kube-api-burst=200 --kube-api-qps=100 -concurrent-resource-quota-syncs=50`. With that, I noticed if I restart k8s-controller and create my pv and pvc definition, it is more *likely* to succeed (still could get stuck). 

Any debugging tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Your PV/PVC definition files have no issues, afaik.

I used them to create a PV and PVC and have them bind without issue:
`NAMESPACE   NAME          STATUS    VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE`
`default     test-0b-pvc   Bound     test-0b-pv   50Gi       RWO           10s`

Could you run `kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces` and `kubectl.sh get pvc` to see if maybe the PV was bound to another PVC?

If that is not the case and you can get a consistent repro, please [open up an issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new) with detailed repro steps, and CC me (`saad-ali`).

Comment: If you were able to solve this issue, please consider posting an answer so the community can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the above answers wrote a solution from perspective of `inconsistent or incorrect` storage class especially in case it was not provided in `PersistentVolumeClaims` however we may have different reason here (described below)

**Problem Statement:**

If you have deleted `PersistentVolumeClaim` and then re-create it again with the same definition, it will be `Pending` forever, why?

**Explanation:**

- we have `"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Retain"` in `PersistentVolume` (the default is retain policy)
- In case we have deleted `PersistentVolumeClaim`, the `PersistentVolume` still exists and the volume is considered `released`. But it is not yet available for another `claim` because the previous claimant's data remains on the volume.
- so you need to manually reclaim the volume with the following steps:

**Solution:**

1. Delete the `PersistentVolume` (associated underlying storage asset/resource like EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, ...etc will NOT be deleted, still exists)
2. (**Optional**) Manually clean up the data on the associated storage asset accordingly
3. (**Optional**) Manually delete the associated storage asset (EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, ...etc)

Please **note** that if you still need same data, simply create a new `PersistentVolume` with same storage asset definition then you should be good to create `PersistentVolumeClaim` again.

One last thing to mention, `Retain` is not the only option for `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy`, here are some other options that you may need to use or try based on use-case scenarios:

**Recycle**: performs a basic scrub on the volume (e.g., rm -rf //*) - makes it available again for a new claim. Only `NFS` and `HostPath` support recycling.

**Delete**: Associated storage asset such as `AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or OpenStack Cinder...etc` volume is deleted

For more information, please check [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#:%7E:text=Retain,data%20remains%20on%20the%20volume.)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding `storageClassName: value` explicitly to both PV and PVC. For the value, I used `standard`.

In this case, the problem might be caused by `DefaultStorageClass` configuration.
For in-depth details, please see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1

Answer (score 2):

I found this confusing too... I was deploying a redis server using helm.  I created a PV, but redis PVC wouldn't take it.  I was like... whaaaat??

then I found this in the docs..

> PVCs don’t necessarily have to request a class. A PVC with its
>   storageClassName set equal to "" is always interpreted to be
>   requesting a PV with no class, so it can only be bound to PVs with no
>   class (no annotation or one set equal to "").

Ahh... So not expressing a preference, is expressing a preference for no preference.  (Yeah, that's like, not confusing at all).

So i created a PV like using a file called pv-volume.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

then

```
kubectl apply -f pv-volume.yaml
```

And viola!  The redis pod took it.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether there is a storageclass set up for your cluster:

```
kubectl get sc
```

Since, you are not specifying any storageClassName here, it will try to get the default one. If the default one doesn't exist or is not gce but something else then it will remain in pending state.

You will need to first register a storageclass for gce and than it should work. You can create storage class for gce like this:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gce
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: none
```

and then you will need to add storageClassName in PVC to make it work